# Can't override Function.prototype on firefox?

Tags: javascript, oop, firefox

The following Javascript code does not have the intended effect:

Function.prototype = {test: "foo"}

Function.prototype is apparently not changed by the assignment (at least on firefox).  Why is this?  Is there a way to override it?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: I've seen people adding stuff to classes they don't own, but this is plain horrible as you're _removing_ system functions from `Function`.

Comment: I'll add that the firefox documentation implies that Function.prototype can be changed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Comment: @user2145275: Setting a property of `Function.prototype` isn't the same as setting the `prototype` property of `Function`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.3.1):

> #### `15.3.3.1 Function.prototype`
>
> The initial value of `Function.prototype` is the standard built-in Function prototype object (15.3.4).
>
> This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

And the part about [[[Writable]]](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.1):

> If `false`, attempts by ECMAScript code to change the property’s [[Value]] attribute using [[Put]] will not succeed.

Comment: thanks; I guess mozilla hasn't caught up to the latest spec yet.  Does this mean there is no way to override function.prototype?  I'm trying to create a (constructor) function that has a few extra inheritable methods.  I could add the methods directly to Function.prototype, but then *every* function would inherit them, which is bad.

Comment: Under strict mode, it will: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function Function() { [native code] }`